# Access 2013: showing query result in a Text box

Tags: vba, ms-access, textbox, ms-access-2013

I have a subform in Access 2013 with the combo boxes CountryCode and CityCode.

I'm adding another field to the subform, a text box where to show the city name that correspond to the country code and the city code entered.

The table Location contains this columns: CountryCode | CityCode | CityName

The SQL query should be:

```
SELECT CityName FROM Location WHERE CountryCode='USA' AND CityCode='NY'
```

'USA' and 'NY' have been chosen by the user in the combo boxes and the resulting CityName should go in the CityName textbox

So far I have done:

In the subform, in the CityName text box Control Source, I have entered:

```
=[GetCityName()]
```

Then in a vba module I have done:

```
Public Function GetCityName()
x = DLookup("[CityName]", "dbo_Location", "[CountryCode] = " & CountryCode & " And [CityCode] = " & CityCode & "")
End Function
```

And this pops up the Enter Macro Name dialog when I run it.

Ok, it may be that I'm not getting the codes from the combo boxes so I change the x to:

```
x = DLookup("[CityName]", "dbo_Location", "[CountryCode] = " & Me.CountryCode & " And [CityCode] = " & Me.CityCode & "")
```

And now I get the error: "The usage of the word Me is not valid"

I'm noticing that the subform is not listed under Microsoft Access Class Objects in vba. Can that be a problem?

Don't know what else to do, as you can see I'm quite new to access and vba. Please help!

Comment: Just refer to the column of the combo. I have no idea why you are making life so complicated for yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain myself. Please, read again. I have edited the question

Comment: In the textbox, eg, `=MyCombo.Column(2)` However, it is a subform, use  a suitable recordset.

Comment: Thanks Remou, but as I said I'm quite new to Access and vba and I don't get what you say :(

Comment: What bit do you not get? What do you want to happen?

Comment: Edited question, please tell me if it is clear now

Comment: Why are you making this so difficult? A combobox can return all the i formationyou want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52384/discussion-between-remou-and-miguel-mas)

Comment: Is that it cannot be done?

Comment: When referring to your comboboxes, why are you not using `.Value`?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
x = DLookup("[CityName]", "dbo_Location", "[CountryCode] = '" & Me.CountryCode.Value & "' And [CityCode] = '" & Me.CityCode.Value & "'")
```